# How to use Watson text-to-speech api in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Im a beginner at using express and node.js. I am confused on how to use Watson api and I can barely understand the documentations/apis. I just want to be able to try using the watson api to my application. So I will just enumerate what I did and where I got stuck.

So first I executed this at the command line, to get the framework.

```
express test
```

Then I did installed the dependencies using this command.

```
cd test && npm install
```

Then I installed watson via the command

```
npm install watson-developer-cloud
```

Then I placed this code at my app.js file.

```
var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
var fs = require('fs');

var text_to_speech = new TextToSpeechV1({
    username: 'INSERT YOUR USERNAME FOR THE SERVICE HERE', (placed my username and password)
    password: 'INSERT YOUR PASSWORD FOR THE SERVICE HERE'
});

var params = {
    text: 'Hello from IBM Watson',
    voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice', // Optional voice
    accept: 'audio/wav'
};

// Pipe the synthesized text to a file
text_to_speech.synthesize(params).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.wav'));
```

So I know that means I am creating a Watson object. But I do not know where to go from here. I just want to be able to create a simple text to speech, wherein there is a textbox and a speak button.

Comment: Did you [look at the examples?](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples) There's a link to them at the NPM page.

Comment: Do you mean the demo?

Comment: No, I mean the examples. The ones I linked to. [Here it is again.](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples) There's an example in there about how to use text to speech.

Comment: Yes, I did. I saw it in the API, but I don't understand how to put it in my code.

Comment: Okay... Are you asking how to send data back and forth between your server and the client (a web interface) then how to play the sound file that the server generates?

Comment: Yes, I want to know what I have to put in my <textarea> and <button> tag.

Comment: Then that is much, much too broad to handle here. Go work through a tutorial on something like [express](https://expressjs.com/) so you can get a server running then you should learn about using a REST API. Once you understand that, it only takes a little bit of work to figure out what you want to do. But learning all of that is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I actually have a server and database running. Is it really hard to put the code needed for a minimal text-to-speech app given that the api is already given?

Comment: Yes. Is your server currently serving up any web pages? How are you handling routes? Are you familiar with AJAX? These all need to be answered before you can move forward.

Comment: Alright I see2x. Do you know any good tutorial or link I can use for those topics?

Comment: I can't think of one that stands out. Just search for "getting started with express" or "getting started with express.js" and you'll find plenty of tutorials on how to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a textbox and a speak button.

Do you mean in a web browser? In that case, you probably want to checkout the [watson-speech](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-speech) SDK instead of the Node.js one.  There's a example at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/v0.20.0/examples/static/text-to-speech.html that does more or less exactly what you're describing.

(Note that the watson-speech browser SDK still requires some server-side code in Node.js or whatever to generate auth tokens. See https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/tree/v0.20.0/examples)

If you would prefer to do it in Node.js for whatever reason, check out the demo https://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net/ & https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-nodejs - the current version uses the Node.js SDK and then sends the audio through Node.js to the browser for playback.

---

Disclosure: I used to work for IBM Watson and I authored the speech-javascript-sdk and parts of the node-sdk. I no longer work there or have any control over these libraries.